# Swift does not support multiple inheritance, How could be achieved?

Tags: swift, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

The following code:

```
class City {
    var cityId : String?
    var cityName : String?
}

class Town {
    var townid : String?
    var townName : String?

}

class Address : City , Town {

    var house : String?
    var street: String?

}
```

Generates a compile-time error:

> Address.swift:38:24: Multiple inheritance from classes 'City' and 'Town'

How can I solve his kind of problem? What approach to follow?

Comment: use custom protocol

Comment: what is purpose here for Multiple inheritance, you can access super class members in multi level case.

Comment: eh, here apparently city can be derived from Town, i.e City: Town. And there should be a protocol let's say IdSupportable { id: String {get}; name: String {get}} Then Town implements IdSupportable, and Address implements the same protocol. But Address is not a city, or Town.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A way to inherit from multiple classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058079/a-way-to-inherit-from-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are overthinking things. Instead of inheritance, try to use more composition. An address should not inherit from `City`. Why? Because logically an address is not a type of city. Instead, city definition is part of the address:

```
class Address { 
    var city: City?
    var town: Town?

    var house : String?
    var street: String?
}
```

Answer (score 6):

*Remark: If you are **unsure** that inheritance the is right choice for your case, I suggest to check [Sulthan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087828/5501940).*

However, As you mentioned, Swift does *not* support multiple inheritance. What you should do instead is to let `Address` class adopts *protocols*; You can also add *Protocol Extensions*:

> You can extend an existing type to adopt and conform to a new
>   protocol, even if you do not have access to the source code for the
>   existing type. Extensions can add new properties, methods, and
>   subscripts to an existing type, and are therefore able to add any
>   requirements that a protocol may demand.

means that you can implement default values/behaviors to a protocol methods/properties.

Referring to your example, it should be similar to:

```
protocol City { }

extension City {
    var cityId: String {
        return "Default City ID"
    }

    var cityName: String {
        return "Default City Name"
    }

    // adding method:
    func doSomething() {
        print("Do Something!!")
    }
}

protocol Town { }

extension Town {
    var townid: String {
        return "Default Town ID"
    }

    var townName: String {
        return "Default Town Name"
    }
}

class Address:City, Town {}
```

Output:

```
let address = Address()

print(address.cityId) // Defaut City ID
print(address.cityName) // Defaut City Name
print(address.townid) // Default Town ID
print(address.townName) // Default Town Name

address.doSomething() // Do Something!!
```

Also, if you want to add some additional job to a method (similar to `super.doSomething()`), you do it like this:

```
class Address:City, Town {
    func doSomething() {
        (self as City).doSomething()
        print("Addtional Job!!")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
let address2 = Address()
address2.doSomething()
// Do Something!!
// Addtional Job!!
```

---

**Take it Further:**

For more information, check [Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) and [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) Documentations.

Also, you might want to watch [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift Apple Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/).

Comment: yea solved my problem ! Multiple inheritance from classes 'City' and 'Town' thank you for response