# How can I establish this design in my project even if I need multiple inheritance for TableViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, inheritance

I am still confused inheritance so I need a instructive approach.I am not new with OOP, so you can go detail if you wish when you answer. Let me explain what I am trying to do. This is not maybe a good approach but I have to do like this because all project has depends on this structure.So sorry if I went something wrong.

Also there is a MotherTableViewController controls the views of view controllers.. I can not share the all project because this is a private repo so I am sorry if you are confused. How can I establish includes my needs and contains below code..

```
class MotherView {
    var sectionNumber: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}

class ChildViewA: MotherView {
    var viewProperty: String = ""
}

class ChilViewB: MotherView {
    var viewProperty: String = ""
}
```

[image]

Comment: So your MotherVC is written in Objective-C and ChildVC is in Swift, and you're trying to access the tableView property of MotherVC from your ChildVC?

Comment: it is very difficult to replicate your issue from the given context above. "I achieved this issue in Storyboard like this". what do you mean by "this". Connecting outlets to File's Owner?

Comment: but as shown above you unwrapp `UINib(nibName: "ChildCellVC", bundle: nil)` where you expect `ChildVc.xib`

Comment: Could you please clarify the following points?
1. "I have created my ChildVC with ChildVc.xib in viewDidLoad" — is this viewDidLoad() method of the MotherVC? Please post the source code so it's easier to understand your setting.
2. `tableView.(UINib(nibName: "ChildCellVC", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")` — this won't even compile, please copy your actual source code.
3. In which method of which VC you're getting the crash? Please post the source code of this method, that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your design pattern little confusing but from my understanding, you can use class inheritance or protocols. I think your confusing point rely on multiple inheritance points. Keep in your mind: Swift does not support multiple inheritances.You can check out this answer if you wish
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087828/11982371

---

I think You can use this Model A or Model B for your case;

**Model A**

```
class MotherTableViewController {
}

class ChildViewAController: MotherTableViewController {
}

class ChilViewBController: MotherTableViewController {
}
```

**Model B**

```
protocol MotherTableViewControllerDelegate {
    var viewProperty: String
    var image: Image
    var name: String
}


class MotherTableViewController {
    func playWithChildren(obj: MotherTableViewControllerDelegate)
}

class MotherView: MotherTableViewControllerDelegate {
}

class ChildViewA: MotherView {
}

class ChilViewB: MotherView {
}
...
```

Also, don`t forget your register for your cell if you say you are getting crash some point

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(cellType: MotherViewCell.self) // basetableview referenced from your MotherViewTableView
    
}
```